# How can I access ith element of any vector without using iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

One can easily get `ith` element by adding `i` to `vector.begin()` is there any ohter way without using iterators?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are talking about `std::vector`, you can use `operator[]` like so:

```
std::vector<int> myVector(10);
myVector[5] = 34;
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` has an [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) defined, and an [`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) method.  Both take an index as input.  The difference is that `operator[]` does not perform bounds checking whereas `at()` does.